# Sort a column alphabetically on a list

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have added a column called Description. The other columns that i use
are SharePoint predefined columns. When I want to make my column sort alphabettically i see in the list settings that you can do only a sort
on the predefined columns. How can I make my list sorting on my created column?

Greetings,

Peter Kiers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that the column isn't a predefined column, but it's most likely a multi line column and that you can't sort on as far as I know.

Comment: Yes its a multiline column. So its not possible to sort on a multiline column?

Comment: Not that I know if out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your custom column anyway, based on my knowledge there is no restriction to sort the column.

You can navigate to List setting -> all way down and select your view and under sort category you can select your custom column by using drop down as mentioned below ... i created a new custom column called New Column test , thats also display in drop down

[image]

And also you can sort by clicking the column name in the Display form, just like how you doing in excel

Comment: Yes its a multiline column. So its not possible to sort on a multiline column?